# check metadata in wordpress

Tags: user-meta

When I made the registration form, I received the contact number from the users and saved it to user_phone Meta_key with the update_user_meta function to the wordpres database.
Now I have trouble verifying that no user enters a duplicate contact number in the field of the form.
How do I validate that if a duplicate contact number is entered during registration, it will show a duplicate contact number error.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: How have you made the registration form? Does it post back to the server? Then in the post handler you can look for duplicate numbers in the database and redisplay the form with an error. Or if it's an AJAX post then again you can check for the duplicate number in the AJAX handler and return an error back to the script somehow.

Comment: If you meant how to actually check the values in the database it's probably going to be simplest to write your own SQL that queries wp_usermeta for matches.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question.
Yes, that's exactly what I mean, but I'm a beginner in backend and I did not find the queries wp_usermeta I was looking for.
I want to search the database when sending Ajax and if the contact number entered in the form was available in the database, a duplicate contact number error would occur.
Just like what the email_exists function does